# Intermediate and root certificates expired but my certificate has not, what happens?

Tags: certificate

I have just renewed a certificate that is used for our web services and asymmetric encryption. I received the following bundle that I will need to provide to my clients, but two of the certificates in the chain are going to expire in May 2020. I've been told by the issuer that there will be no impact, but I'm not convinced as they didn't provide any details as to why there won't be any impact. Can you tell me what will happen on the client side when the root and intermediate certs expire, but my certificate has not? Please see the below image for a clearer picture of the situation.

[Keystore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI3GX.png)

Comment: Certificate        Expiration
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt     05/30/2020  ***
DV_NetworkSolutionsDVServerCA2.crt   09/23/2024
DV_USERTrustRSACertificationAuthority.crt         05/30/2020  ***
Our server cert                      01/28/2022

Comment: Have you attempted this in your test PKI, and what were the results?

Comment: I have not reproduced it with a test certificate store. Planning on doing that this afternoon and will update

Comment: I was able to run a simple test with a local web service. The root cert was expired while the web service certificate was not and the test ran without issue. Still not convinced that this is no issue - anyone have other opinions?